# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} {{(n+1)^k} \over {n^{k+1}}}$ using Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-sum

Find$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} {{(n+1)^k} \over {n^{k+1}}}$$using Riemann sums.

I have: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} {{(n+1)^k} \over {n^{k+1}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} (1 + {1 \over n})^k {1 \over n}$$

Now I need to define a function for using Riemann sums, but I don't really see what it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^k &=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\exp\left(k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\exp\left(\frac{k}{n}\left(1+O(1/n)\right)\right)\\&\to&\int_{0}^{1}e^{x}\,dx=\color{red}{e-1}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: This is tricky actually, because it seems that you cannot convert *exactly* to a sum of the form $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)$. It seems that you are stuck with this $O(1/n)$ correction.

Comment: Being more precise, you have $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \exp \left ( k \left ( \frac{1}{n} + \log \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right ) - \frac{1}{n} \right ) \right ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \exp(k/n) \exp \left ( k \left ( \log \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right ) - \frac{1}{n} \right ) \right )$. So you have this additional factor floating around.

Comment: @Ian so I can't define a function for this problem =\ ...?

Comment: @Stabilo Yes; I think this problem is less direct than most "calculate with a Riemann sum" problems. I think what Jack D'Aurizio did here is about as close as you will get. However, you can do a squeeze theorem trick easily enough: the extra factor is bounded below by $1$ and bounded above by $\exp \left (n \left ( \log(1+1/n) - 1/n \right ) \right )$. Now you take limits in the lower and upper bounds and finish with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Ian thanks, and that's the complete answer

Comment: @Stabilo A minor mistake on my part: actually, $\log(1+1/n)-1/n<0$, so $\exp \left (n \left ( \log(1+1/n)-1/n \right ) \right )=(1+1/n)^n e^{-1}$ is the *lower* bound and $1$ is the *upper* bound.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^k$$ is a geometric sum. And recall that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x^k = x \cdot \dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^k = \dfrac1n\left(1+\dfrac1n\right) \cdot \dfrac{(1+1/n)^n-1}{1/n} = \dfrac{n+1}n \cdot \left((1+1/n)^n-1\right)$$
Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, gives us $e-1$.

Comment: thanks but I specifically asked for Riemann sums

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but is a still a good answer +1

Answer (score 0):

If $0<x<1$ then
$$
1+k\,x<(1+x)^k<1+(k+1)\,x,\quad k\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
The first inequality is obvious by the binomial theorem, while the second one is <strike>easily proved by induction</strike> **false** (see Winther's comment.) Then
$$
\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^k=1+\frac{x_{k,n}}{n},\quad k<x_{k,n}[<k+1\text{ this is false }]
$$

Comment: Please elaborate about how from the inequality you got the equality?

Comment: $$1+\frac{k}{n}<\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^k<1+\frac{k+1}{n}$$

Comment: ok... so what is the function I should define?

Comment: The last inequality, $(1+x)^k < 1+(k+1)x$, is not correct Julian. Just take $x\sim 1$ to get $2^k < 1+(k+1)$.

Comment: @Winther You are wright. The last step in my intended induction proof should have been $>$ instead of $<$.

Comment: See Winther's comment and my edit.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre what is your suggestion for a function I should define?